# Strange behaviour when resizing a Stage with the sizeToScene method in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a problem with resizing a Stage with the sizeToScene method in javafx.

If I change the root node size above the maximum screen size and call sizeToScene, the window resizes well to the maximum possible screen size. 
But if I recall sizeToScene, the scene becomes larger than the stage and the application is cut off.
Sometimes, the first call leads to the same behaviour as the last one described.

I don't know if it is a normal behavior and if there is a workaround solution to adjust the size of the scene to the size of the stage.

The same thing happened on linux and windows.

An example below

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SceneSizeBug extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button("test");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            button.setPrefSize(2000, 2000);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        });
        button.setPrefSize(1280, 1024);
        Scene s = new Scene(button, -1, -1);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just need to set the stage x & y to 0? On my Mac, if the initial size is greater than display size it matches it fills the display (x = y = 0). However, when running your application as is, when I click the button it changes to the same size, but the x and y aren't set to 0, 0 so the application is cut off.

Comment: In my case, on linux, set x & y to 0 doesn't change anything...

Comment: Odd for me setting the stage's x & y in setOnAction results in the same behavior as having the buttons pref size be 2000x2000 initially.

Comment: I would like to point out that I am on a 1920*1080 screen. Setting the resolution to 2000 means that the window must be larger than the screen.